# How can I retrieve $a$ and $b$ from $2^a \cdot 3^b\,$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms, exponentiation

When given a number $k$ in the form $2^a \cdot 3^b$ with integers $a,b$ , I want to use a function $f(k)$ to retrieve $a$ and a function $g(k)$ to retrieve $b$.

I know that prime factorization can help but I want to try avoid algorithmic approaches. I tried taking $\log_2 k$ and $\log_3 k$, but was unsuccessful in manipulating the results to isolate $a$ or $b$.

$$\log_2 k = a + b \log_2 3,$$

$$\log_3 k = b + a \log_3 2.$$

Thanks

Comment: Please, avoid the use of `*` to denote multiplication. That's a common practice in programming, not in Mathematics. When using MathJax simply write `2^a 3^b` ($2^a 3^b$) or `2^a\cdot 3^b` ($2^a\cdot 3^b$)

Comment: This problem is equivalent to finding the integer points on the line $2^x3^y=k$. (This is indeed a line, since we can take logarithm each side as you've done.) Also, there can be only one integer point on the line (for appropriate k, that is, integer k's only having 2 and 3 as prime divisors ), since if there are two, then this violates the uniqueness of integer factorization. Hope this gives some insight.

Comment: Why is it bad to use "*"?

Comment: @markvs that is good question, i dont see any advantage with dot over asterisk, they both valid notation for multiplication to me

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+k+%3D+2%5Ea+%5Ccdot+3%5Eb+for+a

Comment: @markvs, the asterisk is often used in non-math formatting, for instance for creating *italic* or **bold** text (those have 1 and 2 pairs of asterisks around them). It's almost never used in mathematical notation, except sometimes as alternative to "prime" or the like.

Comment: @EricSnyder: So what? Letter "E" is used in many places too, and still you use it in your name.

Comment: hello there fellow @math_enthusiast :)

Comment: @MathEnthusiast314 wow i see in your reddit you make epic desmos graphs!

Comment: @math_enthusiast thanks, thanks for checking it out:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how to interpret the question since ultimately anything you write down in math is going to correspond to some kind of algorithm. That being said, here's one way to try to do it which you can use in programs such as Desmos.

We know that $2^a \le k$ so we can round $k$ down to the nearest power of $2$ and write:

$$2^a = \gcd(k,2^{\lfloor \log_2(k)\rfloor})$$

In other words we have,

$$a = \log_2(\gcd(k,2^{\lfloor \log_2(k)\rfloor}))$$

Of course this is completely general for positive integers, so we can write the p power dividing $k$, called the p-adic valuation $v_p(k)$ as,

$$v_p(k) = \log_p(\gcd(k,p^{\lfloor \log_p(k)\rfloor}))$$

Here's a corresponding [example in desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/xp3epjb13h) to demonstrate.

Comment: THANKS THIS WAS EXACTLY WHAT I WAS LOOKING FOR, it is uncanny that i was looking for this in desmos and you just happened to also include desmos in your answer!!!